# How to get data from snapshot.forEach loop and return through an get route

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new at firebase and have worked a bit with node.js. Basically what I want is to retrieve the data from my collection "coffee" and send it through my /test route so I can work with it on my frontend. I can't figure out how to return it.

I've gotten it to return the first index but not the rest of the list, by putting the return into the forEach loop. But i want to whole list.

```
//test route for database 
router.get("/test", (req, res) =>{
  // For loop goes thorugh our collection list and displays them in log. 
  db.collection('coffee').get().then((snapshot) => {
    let getCoffee = snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      //console.log(doc.data());  
      const dataArray = [];
      dataArray.push(doc.data());
      console.log(dataArray);
    });
    return res.json(getCoffee);

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });


});
```

after edit:

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) =>{    
  // For loop goes thorugh our collection list and displays them in log. 
  db.collection('coffee').get().then((snapshot) => {
    let getCoffee = snapshot.map((doc) => {
      return doc.data();
    });

    return res.json(getCoffee);

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });


});
```

console.log(snapshot) gives me the following:

CollectionReference {
     _firestore:
      Firestore {
        _settings: [Object],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _serializer: [Serializer],
        _projectId: 'test-3ad87',
        registeredListenersCount: 0,
        _lastSuccessfulRequest: 1587563014339,
        _backoffSettings: [Object],
        _preferTransactions: false,
        _clientPool: [ClientPool] },
     _queryOptions:
      QueryOptions {
        parentPath: [ResourcePath],
        collectionId: 'coffee',
        converter: [Object],
        allDescendants: false,
        fieldFilters: [],
        fieldOrders: [],
        startAt: undefined,
        endAt: undefined,
        limit: undefined,
        limitType: undefined,
        offset: undefined,
        projection: undefined },
     _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function] } },
  _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1587563014, _nanoseconds: 390810000 },
  _size: 12,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let getCoffee = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {

      return doc.data();
});
return res.json(getCoffee);
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this? i tried removing and pasting this but get: Error getting documents TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function

Comment: Can you please post the snapshot data structure.

Comment: console.log(snapshot) and post the data

Comment: yep then what?.

Comment: The `snapshot` variable is a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which *does* have a `forEach` method, but not a `map` method.  You'll want to use `snapshot.docs.map(...)` to loop over all documents.

Comment: don't know how or why but i tried doing it again from the beginning and it works. Thanks for hanging in there

Answer (score 1):

Your snapshot operates on a promise within the 'then' and 'catch' blocks. The issue is that your outer get method is complete long before the inner promise complete. Make sure that you return the results of the promise rather than just running it.